# Menu full width of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a menu I want to be the entire width of the site even when I zoom out but can't manage to make it work, this is my code.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>contact</li>
        <li>about</li>
        <ul>
</div>
```

**CSS I Have tried:**

```
#menu {
    width: max;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    height: 75px;
}
```

And

```
#menu {
    width: 1920px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: You should also close your `<ul>` tag with `</ul>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the width 100% -- change it in your CSS to `width: 100%;`

**HTML :**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>contact</li>
        <li>about</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu {

  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  height: 75px;

}
```